# UnitTesting for Silverlight 4

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I'm writing a class library for Silverlight 4, to use as base classes for a MVVM project.
I wanted to unittest it, but was sad to see, that visual studio's fantastic unittesting projects only works for full CLR. What is the recommended way to unittest SL4 libraries (NOT UI - yet...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vc 74 mentions there is UnitTest framework for SL4, that is part of [Silverlight 4 Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). There is also a tool that can help you speed up with working with this framework - take a look here: [Silverlight Testing Automation Tool](http://statlight.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

SL now ships with the SL [unit test framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut)

It is not integrated into the MSTest/VS environment (tests results window...) but works pretty well for testing view models

Answer (score 1):

Further to the Unit Test Framework you may wish to try out the following

Statlight

http://statlight.codeplex.com/

Silverlight unit test framework

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut/

AgUnit

http://agunit.codeplex.com/